# React js State update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was astonished why this setState function is executing after log statement in the below example

```
someMethod = value => {
  this.setState({
    value
  })
  console.log("parent",this.state.value);
}
```

> result :  previous value of value, on the first time it is undefined

Comment: setState is asynchronous. https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Yossi stated setState is asynchronous. If you need the log to execute afterwards you can use a callback in setState like so

```
this.setState({value}, () => console.log("parent":this.state.value));
```